# C++: unordered_map, iterators not comparable

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I've got an `unordered_map` and can not compare the iterators returned by `find()` and `end()`. Here's the situation:

```
unordered_map<IpAddressPort, uint32, IpAddressPortKey> current_sequence_numbers;

...

if (current_sequence_numbers.find(address) == current_sequence_numbers.end()) {
    ...
}
```

Where `IpAddressPort` is just some `struct` and `IpAddressPortKey` looks like this

```
struct IpAddressPortKey {
    inline size_t operator()(const IpAddressPort &p) const {
        return (p.type << 24 | p.addr_ipv4 | p.addr_ipv6.w1 | p.addr_ipv6.w2
            | p.addr_ipv6.w3 | p.addr_ipv6.w4 | p.port);
    }
};
```

The comparison in the `if` block gives this error:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/hashtable.h:892:2:   instantiated from ‘std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Allocator, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, __cache_hash_code, __constant_iterators, __unique_keys>::_Node* std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Allocator, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, __cache_hash_code, __constant_iterators, __unique_keys>::_M_find_node(std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Allocator, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, __cache_hash_code, __constant_iterators, __unique_keys>::_Node*, const key_type&, typename std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Allocator, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, __cache_hash_code, __constant_iterators, __unique_keys>::_Hash_code_type) const [with _Key = reload::IpAddressPort, _Value = std::pair<const reload::IpAddressPort, unsigned int>, _Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const reload::IpAddressPort, unsigned int> >, _ExtractKey = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const reload::IpAddressPort, unsigned int> >, _Equal = std::equal_to<reload::IpAddressPort>, _H1 = reload::IpAddressPortKey, _H2 = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, _Hash = std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, _RehashPolicy = std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, bool __cache_hash_code = false, bool __constant_iterators = false, bool __unique_keys = true, std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Allocator, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, __cache_hash_code, __constant_iterators, __unique_keys>::_Node = std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const reload::IpAddressPort, unsigned int>, false>, std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Allocator, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, __cache_hash_code, __constant_iterators, __unique_keys>::key_type = reload::IpAddressPort, typename std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Allocator, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, __cache_hash_code, __constant_iterators, __unique_keys>::_Hash_code_type = unsigned int]’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/hashtable.h:760:61:   instantiated from ‘std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Allocator, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, __cache_hash_code, __constant_iterators, __unique_keys>::iterator std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Allocator, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, __cache_hash_code, __constant_iterators, __unique_keys>::find(const key_type&) [with _Key = reload::IpAddressPort, _Value = std::pair<const reload::IpAddressPort, unsigned int>, _Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const reload::IpAddressPort, unsigned int> >, _ExtractKey = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const reload::IpAddressPort, unsigned int> >, _Equal = std::equal_to<reload::IpAddressPort>, _H1 = reload::IpAddressPortKey, _H2 = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, _Hash = std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, _RehashPolicy = std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, bool __cache_hash_code = false, bool __constant_iterators = false, bool __unique_keys = true, std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Allocator, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, __cache_hash_code, __constant_iterators, __unique_keys>::iterator = std::__detail::_Hashtable_iterator<std::pair<const reload::IpAddressPort, unsigned int>, false, false>, std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Allocator, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, __cache_hash_code, __constant_iterators, __unique_keys>::key_type = reload::IpAddressPort]’
link_management.cpp:134:51:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_function.h:209:23: error: no match for ‘operator==’ in ‘__x == __y’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_function.h:209:23: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/postypes.h:218:5: note: template<class _StateT> bool std::operator==(const std::fpos<_StateT>&, const std::fpos<_StateT>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:201:5: note: template<class _T1, class _T2> constexpr bool std::operator==(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h:285:5: note: template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator==(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h:335:5: note: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator==(const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h:1025:5: note: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator==(const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::move_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h:1031:5: note: template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator==(const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/allocator.h:122:5: note: template<class _T1, class _T2> bool std::operator==(const std::allocator<_T1>&, const std::allocator<_T2>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/allocator.h:127:5: note: template<class _Tp> bool std::operator==(const std::allocator<_Tp1>&, const std::allocator<_Tp1>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2427:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2434:5: note: template<class _CharT> typename __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<std::__is_char<_Tp>::__value, bool>::__type std::operator==(const std::basic_string<_CharT>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2448:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const _CharT*, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2460:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const _CharT*)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/streambuf_iterator.h:194:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> bool std::operator==(const std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/unordered_map.h:201:5: note: template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Hash, class _Pred, class _Alloc, bool __cache_hash_code> bool std::operator==(const std::__unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc, __cache_hash_code>&, const std::__unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc, __cache_hash_code>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/unordered_map.h:219:5: note: template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Hash, class _Pred, class _Alloc, bool __cache_hash_code> bool std::operator==(const std::__unordered_multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc, __cache_hash_code>&, const std::__unordered_multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc, __cache_hash_code>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/unordered_map.h:384:5: note: template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Hash, class _Pred, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>&, const std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/unordered_map.h:396:5: note: template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Hash, class _Pred, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::unordered_multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>&, const std::unordered_multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_list.h:275:5: note: template<class _Val> bool std::operator==(const std::_List_iterator<_Tp>&, const std::_List_const_iterator<_Val>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_list.h:1564:5: note: template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>&, const std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_deque.h:246:5: note: template<class _Tp, class _Ref, class _Ptr> bool std::operator==(const std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Ref, _Ptr>&, const std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Ref, _Ptr>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_deque.h:253:5: note: template<class _Tp, class _RefL, class _PtrL, class _RefR, class _PtrR> bool std::operator==(const std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _RefL, _PtrL>&, const std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _RefR, _PtrR>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_deque.h:1917:5: note: template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>&, const std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_tree.h:309:5: note: template<class _Val> bool std::operator==(const std::_Rb_tree_iterator<_Tp>&, const std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Val>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_tree.h:846:5: note: template<class _Key, class _Val, class _KeyOfValue, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_map.h:877:5: note: template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_multimap.h:795:5: note: template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_set.h:696:5: note: template<class _Key, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_multiset.h:679:5: note: template<class _Key, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::multiset<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::multiset<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:1273:5: note: template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&, const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&)
```

Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Can you provide the rest of the error? That is clearly just down in the stl implementation and not even the full error for that line, I don't think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have not defined the `operator==()` for the `IpAddressPort` class. You shoud either define `operator==` or define an equity functor and provide it as the 4th template argument

Comment: How could this be the reason when comparing the iterators (and not the structs they're pointing at)? `end()` does not even point to a valid struct, as it's an indicator that the element could not be found.

Comment: This answer is correct, I tested it myself. I cannot find anything in the standard specifically saying that unordered_map requires keys to be equality comparable. I know that keys in std::map are required to be less than comparable (which makes sense, since they are ordered).

Comment: @lefticus: Obviously the unordered map requires equality comparison of elements in order to implement the hash table. This reasoning may not be explicit in the standard, but the equality-comparable requirement most certainly is.

Comment: I thought the problem would be the "==" in my code above - but it's the internally used one by the unordered map. It obviously first checks for equality of the key's hash values, then for key equality.